# PHP MyAdmin After Update Trigger not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

I am using PHP MyAdmin Version 4.1.12.

I am trying to create a simple trigger that, after an update, sets 'dateModified' in table 'person' to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. dateModified is of type TIMESTAMP. The way in which the update occurs to person is the setting of a single attribute in a single record through a X-Editable enabled grid view on a web page. After performing validation against the model with the updated attribute, a new database command is created with the relevant update SQL and executed. So each update only ever modifies a single row within 'person'.

Here is the SQL I wrote to create the trigger:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_AUPD AFTER UPDATE ON person
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @dateModified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

After performing updates, I see that the trigger hasn't fired, and the timestamp remains unchanged from the one they were created with (the default for dateModified, and dateCreated, are both CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, so they get set automatically on insert).

I have looked around for answers, and even looked into alternate methods to getting the update (the alternate method was calling a model's afterupdate method and performing separate SQL there on dateModified). I would prefer to exhaust every opportunity to use the triggers, before I go putting more code into my model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `before update` instead of `after update`. You can't change column values after

Comment: @juergend Thanks, I have set the trigger to before update. However it still is not triggering.

Comment: And use `SET NEW.dateModified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: @juergend Just made that modification, and it works great! Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @juergend, the solution was the following:

- Set trigger type to `before update` because `after update` cannot update attributes, and are best used to insert new records in related audit tables, etc.
- Add `NEW.` to the front of the attribute you wish to modify.